# Diagnose brushless three phase motor controller

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

Can I test somehow if my brushless motor controller works? After some time of playing with it and with the three phases motor from old HHD, this pair just stops working.

LED is on, but nothing more works.
The motor seems to be not damaged. After attaching DC to two (from four) input wires, it starts to shudder a little bit, and it can't be moved (spun) by a hand (it's locked). The values of resistance between the inputs also the same as when I was measuring it before the failure.

After attaching the motor to the controller, nothing happens. It can be spun by hand. Can I find out if the controller is damaged with the multimeter?

This is the type on my controller:

https://alexnld.com/product/5v-12v-dc-brushless-motor-driver-board-controller-for-hard-drive-motor-3-4-wire/

(updated link)

Comment: start by obtaining a schematic diagram of the controller

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me. Can you put the product name and description in your question?

Comment: Link changed. The only thing I've found is https://www.electroschematics.com/hdd-bldc-motor/ Moreover, I'm a newbie so schematic diagram would not help me. I've just rather ask if any output voltage shpuld be visible on multimeter?